# Retrieve all Comments of User (deeply nested)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, nested

Thats my routing:

```
resources :posts do
   resources :comments
  end
```

My User class:

```
has_many :posts
```

My Post class:

```
belongs_to :user
has_many :comments
```

My Comment class

```
belongs_to :post
```

In my User model I want to retrieve all comments. For posts it would be:

```
def all
  Post.where("user_id = ?", id)
end
```

how to get all comments?

Comment: do you want to get all comments that user has written? If you don't store user_id in comments, you can't. If you do, just do the same what with posts.

Comment: yes, thats what i want. so could you give a short answer how to migrate the user_id to comments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My Rails is super rusty, but wouldn't it be something like:

```
def all
    Comment.joins(:post).where(:posts => {:user_id => id})
end
```

Comment: Could not find table 'post'

Comment: try :posts, tables should be plural if following the rails conventions

Comment: That's what I get for writing queries in frameworks I haven't used in months right after waking up. ;)